Image Not being displayed in popup window
Here is the code:
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
 
def CustomerScreen():
    def Page1():
        root = tk.Tk() 
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        root.title("Luxury Sedans, SUVs, Electric Vehicles & More | Audi Dubai | Audi Middle East")
        root['background'] = 'white'
        tk.Label(root, text ="Explore By Models",bg="white",fg="black",font = ("Verdana", 20)).pack()
        C = Canvas(root, bg ="white", height = 250, width = 300)
        load=Image.open("a3side.png")
        img3=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        label1=tk.Label(root,image=img3)
        label1.image=img3
        label1.place(x=0,y=0)
        label1.pack()
        root.mainloop()
    

I am able to display an image on the initial screen after the login page, but when I press the page 1, button an image is supposed to pop up, but it doesn't.
I asked my teacher a couple of days back and my mom, but they don't know what the issue is. I tried multiple methods including chat GPT, and YouTube to get the image from the popup, but nothing worked.
This is the error I am getting:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ypgnv\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:\PYTHON!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\audi website\XI project.py", line 57, in Page1
    label1=tk.Label(root,image=img3)
File "C:\Users\ypgnv\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3187, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Users\ypgnv\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2601, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist

Please help.

The button is working perfectly fine and the text is being displayed. the problem is with the image not being displayed

pls check the error which is given

now can my question be solved?

Try adding master=root inside the ImageTk.PhotoImage(...)

it works thx a lot

It is caused by multiple instances of tk.Tk().  So either use the suggestion by TheLizzard or changing tk.Tk() to tk.Toplevel().  Note also that it is better to call .mainloop() only once.
